# Add new member to class used in override method

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2015, .net-4.5

I have a class that I use in a override method.

The class has 3 members, but I want to add a 4th member in the override method.

Here is what I have.  The code generates errors, but I can't figure out how to fix it or if it's even possible.

my Machine class with 3 members

```
public class Machine
{
    public String PrimarySysName { get; set; }
    public String SysSerial { get; set; }
    public String SecondarySysName { get; set; }
}
```

abstract method for GetMachineDesign

```
protected abstract Object GetMachineDesign(TModel model, TContext context);
```

Override method for GetMachineDesign(trying to add member PrimaryAssemblyLocation):

```
    protected override Object GetMachineDesign(SubSystem model, Design context)
    {
        //add new member            
        public String PrimaryAssemblyLocation;

        return new Machine
        {
            SecondarySysName = model.SecondarySysName,
            SysSerial = model.SysSerial,
            PrimarySysName = model.PrimarySysName

        //set new member here
            set {
               PrimaryAssemblyLocation = context.Location;
            }

        };
    }
```

Comment: It really doesn't make sense what you are trying to do, why inside a method? `public` (or access modifiers in general) don't apply inside methods since they are method scoped. If you want to add a property to the `Machine` class, then subclass it and add the property at the class level, or use an `ExpandoObject`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do such a thing. Either add this member to `Machine` class or create a new derived class which has that additional member, if you cannot modify the `Machine` class.

```
public class MyMachine : Machine
{
    public string PrimaryAssemblyLocation { get; set; }
}
```

The usage:

```
protected override Object GetMachineDesign(SubSystem model, Design context)
{
    return new MyMachine
    {
        SecondarySysName = model.SecondarySysName,
        SysSerial = model.SysSerial,
        PrimarySysName = model.PrimarySysName
        PrimaryAssemblyLocation = context.Location;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.
I suggest you add

```
 public String PrimaryAssemblyLocation;
```

in the same class with your GetMachineDesign method

Answer (score 1):

The killer of your design at the moment is that your `GetMachineDesign` method returns an `Object`. Now when you attempt to de-serialise the `TModel` and `TContext` into a `Machine` you will be tightly coupled when using your abstracted `GetMachineDesign` method between the `PrimaryAssemblyMachine` (calling it this as a guess to what it actually is) and your method, you may as well change the method to be:

```
protected abstract PrimaryAssemblyMachine GetMachineDesign(TModel model, TContext context);
```

As the user of your method will have no clue that your method actually returns a `Machine` that has a `PrimaryAssemblyLocation` property.

I would recommend that you extract the base properties of a machine to an interface and implement other interfaces for each machine that has new properties.

So define your machine like:

```
interface IMachine
{
    String PrimarySysName { get; set; }
    String SysSerial { get; set; }
    String SecondarySysName { get; set; }
}
```

Then have another interface for your machine that looks like:

```
interface IPrimaryAssemblyMachine : IMachine
{
    String PrimaryAssemblyLocation { get; set; }
}
```

Then now you can change the definition of the de-serialiser to:

```
protected abstract IMachine GetMachineDesign(TModel model, TContext context);
```

And then have an overload such as (also assuming you have build an implementer of the `IPrimaryAssemblyMachine`):

```
internal class PrimaryAssemblyMachineBuilder : MachineBuilderBase
{
    protected abstract IMachine GetMachineDesign(TModel mode, TContext context)
    {
        // Do some de-serialisation.
        return new PrimaryAssemblyMachine(primarySysName, 
                                            sysSerial, 
                                            secondarySysName, 
                                            primaryAssemblyLocation);
    }
}
```

This now means that you have removed the coupling between the user of the `GetMachineDesign` from the implementation. And now you can easily make a decision if the `PrimaryAssemblyLocation` property will be available, since it's only on classes that inherit from `IPrimaryAssemblyMachine`.

P.S. sorry about interface/class names, I've just inferred them (badly) from your example.